# How to prevent a Tick event after a Timer has already been initiated

Tags: c#, .net

So I have a Timer object that I'm going to call time, and time has a tick event that is called after 60 seconds are passed. I'm trying to use the time.Stop() method, but the time_Tick() is still called. How do I prevent the Tick method from occuring? Once the Timer has started is there no way of backing out? Thanks! I'm new to Tick events.

Comment: Timer.Stop() should stop the timer, thus not raising the Tick event. You may want to show your code so people can look for an error there.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't for the sake of privacy of my company. I will dig a little deeper and see if the Timer is being restarted by another Thread or something. Thanks for the comment. Will setting time.Enable to false have the same effect?

Comment: Take a look: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Timer.cs,21e9545cfe31887d line 243 onward. `Start` and `Stop` only set the .Enabled property. Its setter (line 157++) then does the work.

Comment: You are using `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`? There are several classes called `Timer` in the .NET framework..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Timer ticks can arrive concurrently and after the timer has been stopped (for fundamental reasons). Ticks could be queued right before you stop the timer.

If you want to reliably stop a timer set a boolean flag and inspect that flag in the tick event handler. If it's set ignore the tick.

You need to synchronize access to that flag.

Answer (score 1):

If you have other timer objects you may be seeing [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.stop%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Calling Stop on any Timer within a Windows Forms application can cause messages from other Timer components in the application to be processed immediately, because all Timer components operate on the main application thread. If you have two Timer components, one set to 700 milliseconds and one set to 500 milliseconds, and you call Stop on the first Timer, your application may receive an event callback for the second component first. If this proves problematic, consider using the Timer class in the System.Threading namespace instead.

Comment: You are absolutely right. After some debugging, I found that the timer I referred to in this question was being restarted by another more general purpose timer in the code. Thanks.

Comment: None of the BCL timers support being stopped reliably.